# SQL | Duplicar filas o tuplas al buscar coincidencias con LIKE

Tags: sql, mysqli

Estoy tratando de construir una consulta que me devuelva varias tuplas cuando en un mismo registro existan varias coincidencias. Expongo un ejemplo muy sencillo.

---

ID | Comentario

1 | Tengo varios telefonos 123456789 y 987654321

2 | Tengo un telefono 741852963

3 | No tengo ningún teléfono

4 | Mi teléfono es 111111111

---

Consulta:

SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE comentario LIKE "%123456789%" OR comentario LIKE "%987654321"% OR comentario LIKE "%111111111"%

Mi ojetivo es que me devuelva:

El registro con ID 1 dos veces dado que hay 2 coincidencias y el registro con ID 4 una vez dado que sólo hay una coincidencia. Con la consulta que arriba expongo el registro con ID aparece tan sólo una vez.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me parece que ese disennno no es el mas correcto, creo que deberias tener una tabla de telefonos que se relacione con tu otra tabla ya que como bien dices en tu ejemplo se pueden tener varios telefonos

Comment: Dado que tienes esos datos en un solo registro, lo que tendrías que hacer es varias consultas, una por cada teléfono que quieras buscar, y al final puedes hacer un unión ALL, para que te regrese  todos los items.

Answer (score 0):

Esta quizás no sea la mejor solución, pero funciona para el escenario que planteaste.

```
select ID,  value NumeroTelefonico
from
(
    select ID, REVERSE( SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(Comentarios,PATINDEX('%[0-9,]%', Comentarios),LEN(Comentarios)+1)),   
                PATINDEX('%[0-9,]%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(Comentarios,PATINDEX('%[0-9,]%', Comentarios),LEN(Comentarios)+1))),
                LEN(Comentarios)+1))Comentarios
    from 
    (
                select 1 ID, 'Tengo varios telefonos 123456789 y 987654321 que no es mio' Comentarios
        union all select 2 , 'Tengo un telefono 741852963'
        union all select 3 , 'No tengo ningún teléfono'
        union all select 4 , 'Mi teléfono es 111111111' 
    )t
)t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.Comentarios, ' ' )
where ISNUMERIC(value )=1
```